# Android - How to check if a textview is currently showing keyboard input

Tags: android, focus, textview

I have an activity where a text view gains focus of a keyboard.

I set an ontouchlistener to the parent view; if the click is outside the range of the textview, I am hiding my textview by using ;

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

My only problem is, if the keyboard is not showing and the parent is clicked on, it keeps firing up those two lines, which ultimately causes useless transactions (I like to save as much processing as possible ..)

I have been trying to use some textview methods like hasfocus or isfocused etc but I can't quite seem to find one that only fires off the text view makes a keyboard show ...

Does anyone know if this is even possible?

THe if statement below is the place I would like to put the method ..

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            if (textView.*SOME METHOD HERE*?) {
                Log.e(TAG, "LOSING FOCUS");
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(textView.getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        }
                    return true;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Check the configuration.  The keyboardHidden value will hold whether any keyboard is out.  This will work unless there's a face keyboard (think Blackberry style).  If those are important you'll need some more complicated logic including the keyboard field and hardKeyboardHidden fields.